# ImportError: No module named py31compat

Tags: python, python-2.7, importerror, gensim

i am trying to install gensim using

```
sudo -H pip install --upgrade gensim
```

but it is giving me this error :

```
  File "setup.py", line 301, in <module>
    include_package_data=True,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command                      /install.py", line 67, in run
    self.do_egg_install()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command /install.py", line 98, in do_egg_install
    easy_install = self.distribution.get_command_class('easy_install')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 576, in get_command_class
    self.cmdclass[command] = cmdclass = ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2229, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2235, in resolve
module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 47, in <module>
from setuptools.sandbox import run_setup
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 15, in <module>
    import pkg_resources.py31compat
ImportError: No module named py31compat
```

please help me, in installing gensim. i googled it, but i am not able to find the solution.

Comment: Try `sudo pip install pkg_resources` or `sudo apt-get install python-pkg_resources`

Comment: replay me if it works

Answer (score 1):

It looks like setuptoopls is missing. Try

```
$sudo pip install setuptools
```

Comment: tried anonymous miliana's comment. it worked. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Notice that `setuptools` come from `/usr/local/lib` whereas `pkg_resources` come from `/usr/lib`. You must likely have an older pkg_resources through the package system and then a newer setuptools installed by pip.

Delete (or move away) the `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools` directory.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a very similar error upon an Ansible run of a refactored OpenShift playbook.  The error was discovered once all of the plays were parsed.

"ERROR! Unexpected Exception, this is probably a bug: cannot import name py31compat"

I am using ...

- Ansible 2.5.3
- Python2-2.7.15

I ran the following command to list the location of all of the packages and libraries associated with Python 2.  I checked available paths to ensure I had one version of Ansible and one copy of each package installed.

$ python -c 'import sys; print sys.path'

'py31compat' is not a separate module one can download.  It is included with the Setuptools package.  It was determined I had two packages installed of different versions, both out-of-date.  I uninstalled both via pip and installed the latest setuptools version available.  No luck.

My solution was to uninstall Ansible and reinstall the same version.  This resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i have odoo v10 installed and for any weird reason update or installed a library that stuck my server and not longer to start with XOE.

The error was:

***cannot import name py31compat***

After 1 hour trying many differents things i decide uninstall:

```
sudo pip uninstall setuptools
```

> ```
> Uninstalling setuptools-40.8.0:   Would remove:
> /usr/local/bin/easy_install
> /usr/local/bin/easy_install-2.7
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/easy_install.py
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/*
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-40.8.0.dist-info/**
> ```

And my service odoo server starts and works fine again!