# Python pip py31compat import error

Tags: python, macos, pip

When I try to install any package via pip on MacOS Sierra, I encounter the following error:

```
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import pkg_resources
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3018, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3004, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3046, in _initialize_master_working_set
    dist.activate(replace=False)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2578, in activate
    declare_namespace(pkg)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2152, in declare_namespace
    _handle_ns(packageName, path_item)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2091, in _handle_ns
    loader.load_module(packageName)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pkgutil.py", line 246, in load_module
    mod = imp.load_module(fullname, self.file, self.filename, self.etc)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/PyObjCTools/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
  File "/Users/jiaseny/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    from . import py31compat
ImportError: cannot import name py31compat
```

Trying `sudo pip install pkg_resources`, `sudo pip install setuptools` as suggested in [ImportError: No module named py31compat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46998858/importerror-no-module-named-py31compat#)
resulted in the same error.

Perhaps I should try uninstalling and reinstalling `pip`? But `sudo pip uninstall pip` and  `sudo easy_install pip` resulted in the same errors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the path to your python, I can see you're not using the system python which is installed natively, nor are you using homebrew or pyenv, either of which I would highly recommend.

[Pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) is my preferred method of installation for development purposes. A manual install is straight forward and only mildly more difficult than with homebrew, and its one less thing relying on a relatively opaque box to function. The recommended install from the [README](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#installation) is just:

```
git clone https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv.git ~/.pyenv
echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo -e 'if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then\n  eval "$(pyenv init -)"\nfi' >> ~/.bash_profile
exec "$SHELL"
pyenv install 2.7.14
pyenv global 2.7.14
```

Alternatively if you use [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) you can just `brew install pyenv`, and I believe it will set everything up for you, before the `pyenv install`.

Or if all you want is a somewhat more up to date python than the system one, install homebrew and `brew install python`.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up reinstalling python which solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In case you come here through Google, I had similar issue on MacOS. I tried the the accepted answer it did not work. But doing these upgrade resolved it for me:

> pip install --upgrade pip
>
> pip install --upgrade setuptools
>
> pip install --upgrade distribute