# Missing pkg_resources.py31compat

Tags: python, virtualenv, pkg-resources

I tried to set up a virtualenv and I have setuptools (39.0.1). And I got

```
In [1]: import pkg_resources.py31compat
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-136e80f945a9> in <module>()
----> 1 import pkg_resources.py31compat

ImportError: No module named py31compat
```

I read elsewhere that installing the latest setuptools should fix this. But apparently, it didn't work.

Please help.

(additional info in comments)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named py31compat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46998858/importerror-no-module-named-py31compat)

Comment: I tried upgrading setuptools but the problem still persists. I think something is wrong from "virtualenv --system-site-packages", I am able to locate py31compat.py under the virtualenv directory:    ./lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/py31compat.py,
./lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/py31compat.py, but importing it like above will fail.